# Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'method group'

Tags: c#, linq

Probably a duplicate but of the related questions, I've yet to find a solution that works. Trying to count the number of digits up to a a number of character in a string.

Getting the error: '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'method group'

```
line.TakeWhile(!Char.IsLetterOrDigit).Count())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use lambda expression instead of method group syntax here:

```
line.TakeWhile(x => !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(x)).Count())
```

Answer (score 2):

the problem is exactly what the error tells you: you cannot use `!` on an function (the `Char.IsLetterOrDigit`) - one simple solution is expanding it into a lambda:

```
line.TakeWhile(c => !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)).Count())
```